# dropzone return cross domain error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm tring to upload a file using dropzone, but when I upload the file through across domains it shows me a *cross domain error*.

**Html**

```
<img style="cursor: pointer;"  class="ui medium bordered image" name="fotomural" onchange="javascript{$('#fbftmural').val(this.src)}" id="FPFtmural" src="../dummyimage.png">
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#FPFtmural").dropzone({
    url:'localhost:8000/pessoas/uploadfoto',
    uploadMultiple: false,
    autoProcessQueue: true,
    withCredentials: true,  //cross domain property
    init: function() {
        var dropzone = this;
        this.on("success", function(file,xmlResponse) {
            console.log(xmlResponse);
        });
    }
});
```

**error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/pessoas/uploadfoto. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.Dropzone.submitRequest @ dropzone.js:1371Dropzone.uploadFiles @ dropzone.js:1367Dropzone.processFiles @ dropzone.js:1161Dropzone.processFile @ dropzone.js:1147Dropzone.processQueue @ dropzone.js:1140(anonymous function) @ dropzone.js:1004

Comment: change localhost to real url